# How do I use the "or" operator between different elements?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Help me please!

```
[GET] http://fhir.hl7fundamentals.org/r4/ServiceRequest?encounter:Encounter.participant.identifier=teste-brasil-v1|123abc456
```

The result is 1

```
[GET] http://fhir.hl7fundamentals.org/r4/ServiceRequest?encounter:Encounter.participant.practitioner.identifier=teste-brasil-v1|123abc456
```

The result is 2

I would like to put both parameters in the same url, but with the "or" operator, something like:

...? encounter:Encounter.participant.identifier=teste-brasil-v1|123abc456 or encounter:Encounter.participant.practitioner.identifier=teste-brasil-v1|123abc456

Objective is in a single url to obtain the result of 2 records

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a standard RESTful search.  You'd have to use [_filter](https://build.fhir.org/search#filter) which gives you the ability to 'or' parameters together.  With REST, you can only do 'or' with the values for a single criteria.  For example, you could search for encounters that have participants with identifier A or B (by separating the values you want to match on with ',').

Be aware that _filter isn't widely supported, so it may not be available on the server you're using.

Another option is to execute two separate queries, but send them in a [batch](https://build.fhir.org/http.html#transaction) so you only have to make one call.  You'll end up with two result sets, and you'll have to page them independently, but it does let you get away with a single call.

Comment: Thank you very much Lloyd McKenzie

Could you please tell me how my url will look with "_filter"?

Because my url has chained search.

Comment: `?_filter=encounter:Encounter.participant.identifier eq teste-brasil-v1|123abc456 or encounter:Encounter.participant.practitioner.identifier=teste-brasil-v1|123abc456`

(note that you'd need to escape the spaces)

Comment: How do I know that the server supports the "_filter"?

I ask, because on the server "http://fhir.hl7fundamentals.org", I ran the [GET] http://fhir.hl7fundamentals.org/r4/ServiceRequest?_filter=encounter:Encounter.participant.identifier eq teste-brasil- v1 | 123abc456 or encounter: Encounter.participant.practitioner.identifier = teste-brasil-v1 | 123abc456

according to your guidance and I obtained the return of all resource records

Comment: The server's CapabilityStatement should list what search parameters are supported.

Answer (score -3):

The [Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) ( | ) returns a 1 in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are 1s

The [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) ( || ) returns  true if and only if one or more of its operands is true the first true operand is returned or false if all operands are false

```
const a = 5;        // 00000000000000000000000000000101
const b = 3;        // 00000000000000000000000000000011

console.log(a | b); // 00000000000000000000000000000111
// expected output: 7
```

```
const a = 3;
const b = -2;

console.log(a > 0 || b > 0);
// expected output: true
```